# Appium cannot get to automate a particular field why?

Tags: appium

I'm working in appium. It couldn't get automate a enter password field. Only issue is enter password field login button click is working fine .I tried by using with xpath, cssselector and also className, But not get to autoamte.
code for enter password then click on login button

```
public Login invalidLogin() {



        MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'main\']/div[1]/form/div[1]/div/label/input"));
        element.sendKeys("9400693133");
        MobileElement element1 = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'main\']/div[2]/div[1]"));
        element1.click();



   WebDriverWait waitElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@type=‘password’]")));

            MobileElement element2= (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type=‘password’]"));
            element2.sendKeys("abcd");

   waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@ng-click='sentloginrequest(login_passwd)']")));

            MobileElement element3= (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@ng-click='sentloginrequest(login_passwd)']"));
            element3.click();

    return new Login(driver);
```

Error:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //input[@type=‘password’] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
```

And I tried this too put `xpath("//input[@ng-model=‘login_passwd’]")`
Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //input[@ng-model=‘login_passwd’] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code looks like your app is build in Angular JS.

can you try following code.

```
WebDriverWait waitElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(“//input[@type=‘password’]”)));

MobileElement element4= (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//input[@type=‘password’]”));
element4.sendKeys(“1233”);

waitElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(“//div[@ng-click='sentloginrequest(login_passwd)']”)));

MobileElement element4= (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@ng-click='sentloginrequest(login_passwd)']"));
element4.click();
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@ng-click='sentloginrequest(login_passwd)']"}

Comment: I want to both enter pasword and click login button. I couldn't get to autoamte till now

Comment: @comrade updated answer try adding wait before performing actions on element

Comment: I had edited please check   Login click button is working fine and only issue with enter password field

Comment: This will work fine xpath("//input[@maxlength='4']")  .  THanks for the support